# Support of pagination in smartGWT for ListGrid?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, listgrid

I have noticed after some research that **smartGWT** don't support pagination in the `ListGrid` but only dynamic scroll. But if I really need pagination, how can I achieve this?

Let's say I want something like this with the "**next**" and "**previous**" buttons:

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

**PS:** This example is in GWT, what I want is something similar but in smartGWT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry that there is no Paging component in SmartGWT. But some nice guy has written a component called GridPager, which could meet your requirement, I think.

GridPager should works with ListGrid.

You can find the information of the component by googling.

There is also a discussion about the paging function of SmartGWT, I think it helps.
The url is http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=3103

GridPager is also mentioned in the discussion.

Comment: Link seems unresponsive. Where do they have it nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something "similar", not precisely the same, why don't you...

- Implement dynamic scroll
- Extend `ListGrid` and add two buttons wherever you want
- Have the buttons scroll up/down as if those are the previous/next "pages"?

Comment: Pagination is the exact opposite of dynamic scroll because once you scroll down, the previous results remains there and if for example I want to select all lines of Page 2, this wouldn't work because all the previous lines (from Page 1) would be selected too ...

Comment: @AdelBoutros, it's just a matter of overriding the `selectAll` (or creating a `selectPage()`) behavior and defining the number of "lines" a "page" has... keeping the contents of previous pages in the browser shouldn't present a problem, unless your user spans hundreds of pages (and even so, SmartGWT probably has something to clear older results).

Comment: Your proposed solution will require complexe operations. It would far easier for me to make a datasource per Page and let the previous/next buttons swap the currently loaded DataSource.

Comment: But I was wondering is there a way to ask the datasource to only fetch for example 50 lines and then on each click of previous/next button tell it to fetch the next or previous 50 lines?